# Patch network to "connect the dots" and assess overall area belonging to an agent's "home range"

Tags: netlogo

I have agents moving through a landscape with varying resources. Say my agent begins in the center, and then moves around the landscape in a curved line. I would like to somehow make a patchset or other grouping of ALL the patches that encompass the area within the patches through which the agent moved, simulating a home range calculation. I haven't been able to think conceptually of how to do this so I have no code to show, but any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you define the meaning of "the area within the patches through which the agent moved"? Are we talking about "only the patches traversed by the agent" or something broader like "the smallest square area encompassing all the patches traversed by the agent"?

Comment: Yes, the second. Equivalent to calculating a home range for an animal from its location points (if you're familiar with MCP analysis)

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is probably just to keep track of the min/max of the coordinates of the patches visited by turtles. Here is a simplistic example:

```
turtles-own [ min-x max-x min-y max-y ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask patches [ set pcolor black ]
  ask turtles [
    rt random 30 lt random 30 fd 1 ; move randomly
    update-min-max
    ask home-range [ set pcolor [ color ] of myself - 2 ]
  ]
  tick
end

to update-min-max ; turtle command
  set min-x min (list min-x pxcor)
  set min-y min (list min-y pycor)
  set max-x max (list max-x pxcor)
  set max-y max (list max-y pycor)
end

to-report home-range ; turtle reporter
  report patches with [
    pxcor >= [ min-x ] of myself and
    pxcor <= [ max-x ] of myself and
    pycor >= [ min-y ] of myself and 
    pycor <= [ max-y ] of myself
  ]
end
```

This assumes that the world doesn't wrap.

Comment: I was thinking about this problem. This will give you the rectangle, but doesn't help with curves (that is, where the corner is cut off with the path). I think OP is actually after the convex set (maths term) bounded by the points visited. But the only way I can work out how to do that is to create a patch set of all the patches visited and then take all pairs and identify the patches between them with a crawler type of turtle. Horribly inefficient.

Comment: Failing that, the only approach i can think of is to retain the min-pxcor and max-pxcor for each value of pycor, and similarly the min-pycor and max-pycor for each value of pxcor. Perhaps a table? Then create the patchset between the min/max pairs.

Comment: The OP acquiesced to the "square area" definition, but if they prefer a convex hull, there is a full Wikipedia page of algorithms to choose from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms. It seems like some of them wouldn't be too hard to implement in NetLogo... :-)

Comment: Fair enough. I interpreted the acquiescence as 'more like' rather that 'exactly like'